# Is $1-f(x)\to 0$ equivalent with $f(x)\to 1$.

Tags: calculus, limits

**Problem.** I am trying to make a proof of contradiction and have this far shown that if my assumption is true, both $$\lim_{x\to 0}(1-f(x))=0\quad \text{and}\quad \lim_{x\to 0}(1+f(x))=0$$ must be true. That seems impossible, but I am not entirely sure how to prove that that actually is the case.

**My thoughts.** I first tried to rewrite the limit like this: $$\lim_{x\to 0}(1-f(x))= \lim_{x\to 0}(1)-\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=1-\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0\Leftrightarrow \lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=1$$ and then do the same with the other limit (which give the conclusion $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=-1$. But is that valid if we don't know on beforehand that \lim_{x\to 0}f(x) exists? Unless this isn't a special case somehow, it shouldn't be, so it seems like I need a better approach :/

Comment: What are your assumptions?  I don't follow how you getting that both of limits hold.  It is true that $1-f(x)\to 0$ if and only if $f(x)\to 1$.

Comment: f(x) = 1 - (1 - f(x)). Since 1 and f(x) - 1 both have well-defined limits at zero, f(x) does as well.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} (1\pm f(x))$ exists if and only if $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} f(x)$ exists. Then you have the limit laws. So you may be able to say "Suppose the limit exists. Then ... contradiction".